# Access Autonumber and Maintaining Uniqueness in Multi-user Database

Tags: ms-access

Somewhat general question about Access, but hopefully has a fairly easy answer:

When you use autonumber in a shared multi-user database, is Access doing anything in particular to ensure that the number it assigns is unique what with other users adding records at the same time?

Does it immediately claim the next number for the first user who has connected to that table, or does it wait until the new record is about to be saved and check the highest number of all saved records in the table just before assigning the next number?

Is its uniqueness robust in a multi-user environment?

Comment: Btw, this is rather good question (^)

Comment: It basically starts a transaction. If you open a form bound to  table with an autonumber PK, it locks that number. Autonumbers will absolutely guarantee you uniqueness, but not order. If User A starts a transaction and User B starts a transaction on the same table, user A will have the lock on the number 1 while user B has a lock on 2. If user A doesn't commit the data, User B will insert the first record into the table with ID of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fully answer your question it is important to make the distinction between

- "Access" (the application), and
- the "Access Database Engine" (a.k.a. "ACE") and its predecessor, the Jet database engine.

> When you use autonumber in a shared multi-user database, is Access doing anything in particular to ensure that the number it assigns is unique what with other users adding records at the same time?
>
> [...]
>
> Is its uniqueness robust in a multi-user environment?

Yes. ACE, like many other database engines, ensures that Identity columns (what Access calls "AutoNumber fields") are unique in a multi-user environment by normally assigning that number at the time the record is committed (written) to the table. However, ACE does offer Access the opportunity to get its AutoNumber value in advance (see below).

> Does [Access] immediately claim the next number for the first user who has connected to that table,

No. Simply "connecting to" a table (e.g., by doing a SELECT, or opening a Recordset) does not affect the counter of an AutoNumber field.

> or does [Access] wait until the new record is about to be saved and check the highest number of all saved records in the table just before assigning the next number?

That depends...

If the "table" is a linked table to an ODBC data source (e.g., a SQL Server table with an IDENTITY column) then yes, Access "waits" until the user does something that will commit (save) the new record, at which point it submits the new record to the database server and then retrieves the AutoNumber value for that record (e.g., via `SELECT @@IDENTITY` in SQL Server, or a similar mechanism for other database engines).

However, if the "table" is a native ACE/Jet table then you may notice that the new AutoNumber value appears immediately after you start typing into a new record (e.g., in Datasheet View, or in a bound form). In this case Access (the application) tells ACE (the database engine) that it *may* want to insert a new record and requests the AutoNumber value right away. ACE returns the value and increments the counter so another user making the same request will get the next number in the sequence. Note that this process "consumes" the AutoNumber value: it will either be used (if the user saves the record) or discarded (if the user decides not to save the record) but it won't be re-used. That's why

- ACE AutoNumber fields that are "incrementing" (as opposed to "random") sometimes have "gaps" in them, and
- if you start entering data, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the insert, and then start typing again, the AutoNumber value is different (because you "consumed" the previous AutoNumber value even though you did not save the record).

Comment: Great explanation - particularly about ACE "consuming" the number at the point the new record is started. Thank you.

Comment: The Informix RDB server I use assigns the next available SERIAL (Autonumber) value at the moment a client commits to the server. I tend to like this method better since it does not create any gaps in the sequence, should a client abort the commit.

Comment: Is there any way to tell ACE to wait until the record is committed and then assign the autonumber? I don't like the idea of using up a number with no data along with it. If we were to get audited by regulatory government agencies, it would raise a lot of red flags!

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom Notice in my answer that the "pre-allocation" of an AutoNumber in Access happens when the user starts entering data "directly into the table" (either in Datasheet View, or via a bound form). You can always use an unbound form to capture the data and write it back to the table when appropriate, creating the AutoNumber value at that time. Also, if auditors require sequential numbering (e.g. for invoices) then one could argue that using an AutoNumber field is simply not the appropriate choice, since AutoNumber values should **only** be used as unique row identifiers.

Comment: Yes, the local Laws and Regulations of the Pawnbroker industry I work in require sequential numbering for Pawns, Purchases and Sales receipts. If I rolled my own sequencing routine, it wouldn't work properly in a multi-user environment. So, just because of ACE's limitation on how it Autonumber's, it means I would have to use another SQL-based engine, unless there's a way to toggle ACE's method.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom For Access 2010 and later the sequential number could be an ordinary Long Integer (instead of an AutoNumber) and generated by an event-driven data macro.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: Yes, it is. MS Access Database, as any other general RDB, is well suited to operate in multi-user environment (**though performance-wise it might be not that fast as, for e.g. SQL Server, and it's data security model is not that sophisticated**). Also, the uniqueness of the primary key (i.e. autonumber) is provided on the table level; in other words, it's not a GUID (globally unique ID).

Comment: If Ms Access is perfectly suited to operate in multi-user environment why do ppl prefer SQL for multi user enviornment ?

Comment: Depends on how many users you have, your performance needs, your resources, etc...

Comment: Other RDB may provide better performance and data security, as I put in my answer.