# Maintaining AutoNumber functionality in a form while using SQL backend

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Currently, I am trying to move from an Access backend to a SQL backend for my database while still keeping the Access form as the frontend. This is done via linked tables with ODBC connections to my backend. The form is designed to add new records to the table. The problem is with AutoNumber. The ID was set as an AutoNumber and the form would simply display (New) while waiting for the user to add the remaining columns. I have set up my SQL data with the IDENTITY property, so it will increment once a new record is created. However, I cannot get the form to behave the same way as it did because, even though the backend will automatically add the next sequential ID, I cannot automatically fill that data into the form prior to a user actually saving the form data. Is there a way maintain the form functionality that AutoNumber provides?

TL;DR: Form is not working correctly after AutoNumber is changed to Number.

Comment: You may find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16473079/2144390) to be of interest.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are "rare" cases in which you actually need the autonumberr before you save the record. For example, if you have a sub-form, then Access ALWAYS does a automatic save of the main record, and thus the autonumber is and will have been created .So a main form, and sub form (child  table) will work fine, and do so without code.

Now, there are some cases in which you need the autonumber. Say you have some "code" that needs to run and spit out some child records.

The general approach is to simply execute a record save at that point in time.

So, say there is a button, or some code you need to run in the form, and you NEED the PK autonumber?

You can use this code:

```
If isnull(me!ID) = true then
   me.dirty = false  ' force record save - autonumber now created
end if
```

the record for above to work will have to be "dirty", but in near all cases, this tends to be the case. The "rare" exceptions would suggest that you could check me.IsNewRecord, but in most cases the above bit of code will suffice.

I can't really imagine that the "display" of some autonumber is oh so important WHEN the user is starting to enter data.

However, if you want the autonumber to appear after ANY keypress (data entry on the form)?

Simply put  this line of code in the after insert event:

```
me.dirty = false
```

So, now when looking at a form, the FIRST key press by the user in any text box will force the autonumber to be generated and appear. However, it is a VERY bad practice to assign any meaning of the autonumber ID to the end users. In fact that ID should in most cases be hidden.

the only issue or downside of above is of course that if you have any required columns, then the above may error out or case an issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

For this problem, I needed to set my identity_insert to ON in the SQL backend. Here is the code to do so:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON;
```

Also, if you get the error: `Table <Table Name> does not have the identity property.` recreate the table with the autoincrementing column having an identity.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE new_employees  (id_num int IDENTITY(1,1), fname varchar (20), minit char(1),  lname varchar(30));
```

More on IDENTITY in Microsoft offical documentation: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Not sure why you need to do this? For any recordset, or even a sql insert, access ALWAYS sends a identity insert command for you. This is the default operation of Access, and access sends this command to sql server FOR ALL AND EVERY update or insert. Access does this to maintain compatibility with Access which by default allows you to insert a PK auto number column in code, or even by cut + paste.  You should not have to issue this command. See my post below in which adding ONE line of code to a form will re-produce the behavior of autonumber appearing when the user first hits a key.